# compiling using a Makefile

Tags: makefile

gcc 4.4.4

I have the following Makefile

```
OBJECT_FILES = brd.o logger.o test_brd.o
CFLAGS = -m32 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -D_REENTRANT -D_THREAD_SAFE -O0 -D_DEBUG

# Linker Run-time library path
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=/usr/NET/lib 

FLATFORM = -DLINUX
TARGET = dlg
CC = gcc -m32

LIBS_PATH = -L/usr/NET/lib
INC_PATH = -I/usr/NET/include

LIBS = -lnc -lnxx -lphread

$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) $(FLATFORM) $(INC_PATH) $(LIBS_PATH) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET)

test_brd.o: test_brd.c brd.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) test_brd.c

brd.o: brd.c logger.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) brd.c

logger.o: logger.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INC_PATH) logger.c

clean: 
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

However, the logger.c doesn't need to be built anymore. Is there a way to include it in the project without having to compile it each time. When I clean my project. It will re-compile it again, and it is a large file.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change:

```
OBJECT_FILES = brd.o logger.o test_brd.o
```

into:

```
OBJECT_FILES_EXCEPT_LOGGER = brd.o test_brd.o
OBJECT_FILES = $(OBJECT_FILES_EXCEPT_LOGGER) logger.o
```

and change your clean to:

```
clean: 
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECT_FILES_EXCEPT_LOGGER)
```

But the whole *point* to clean is to do a full rebuild. If you don't want a full rebuild, just use `make` on its own and it'll build only what it needs to. With a properly built makefile, you should almost never need to do a full rebuild (the only exception I can think of to that is when you change the makefile itself but I even bypass *that* by making all rules depend on the makefile as well).

By the way,

```
brd.o: brd.c logger.c
```

and

```
test_brd.o: test_brd.c brd.c
```

don't seem write to me - there's no dependency between `brd.o` and `logger.c`, nor between `test_brd.o` and `brd.c` (at least based on your compilation statements). The only way you would have a dependency is if you `#include`'d one C file within another, and that's rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

What your `Makefile` says is that `logger.c` should be recompiled if and only if it is newer than `logger.o` if that exists. What I think you probably want is

```
.PRECIOUS: logger.o
```

somewhere in your file to tell make that `logger.o` may be an intermediate file, but should not be removed whenever make thinks it's not going to need it any more. Maybe even

```
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

to extend the effect to all three object files.

Edit: Er, you do realize that there is usually no need to call `make clean`, right? Make is all about handling dependencies for you and only rebuild what is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
SMALL_OBJECT_FILES = brd.o test_brd.o
OBJECT_FILES = $(OBJECT_FILES) logger.o

...

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(SMALL_OBJECT_FILES)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't update the timestamp on `logger.c`, and don't remove `logger.o`, then the file will not get recompiled.

The issue is that your `clean` target is removing `logger.o`.  Provided that `logger.o` is really used by your final binary, recompiling is unavoidable.

You must relax one of two constraints:

- Having `make clean` actually remove all intermediate object files
- Having `logger.c` get recompiled after each `make clean; make`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing `logger.o` from the Makefile like this:

```
OBJECT_FILES = brd.o test_brd.o
```

**EDIT:**

and of course:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECT_FILES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECT_FILES) logger.o $(FLATFORM) $(INC_PATH) $(LIBS_PATH) $(LIBS) -o $(TARGET)
```